# Set color of open Bootstrap 4 accordion panel on page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-accordion

I want to highlight the panel which has been opened by the user.  When a user clicks the button in the card-header the background is set to red. This works without any fuss, as shown in the snippet.

In some cases I'll have a panel, usually the first, open on page load, which I set with the class `show`. My goal is the set the background of this card-header to red as well on page load.

The buttons in the card-headers are set using js, as shown in the code snippet.

I reckon I have to use javascript to toggle classes.

First I added a new class `highlight` and added the following CSS code:

```
.accordion .card-header.highlight {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Then I added the following js (please be aware that I find js quite difficult to comprehend, albeit slowly but surely I'm learning) to try set the background of the header of the open pane on page load.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Add class highlight to panel with show class
    $(".collapse.show").each(function(){
        $(this).prev(".card-header").addClass("highlight");
    });
    
    // toggle highlight class
    $(".card-header .btn").click(function(){
        $(".card-header").toggleClass("highlight");
    });
});
```

I looks very messy, probably because it is, and doesn't produce the desired result.

How can I set the background (red) of the header of the open panel on page load and how can I toggle classes using js?

```js
/** Accordions JavaScript **/
/** Dynamically add id **/
$.each($(".accordion"), (function (index) {
   $(this).attr("id", "accordion_" + parseInt(index + 1));
}));

/** Dynamically add interaction **/
$.each($(".accordion > .card"), (function (index, value) {
   var num = index + 1;
   $(value).children(".card-header").attr("id", "heading_acc_" + num);
   $(value).find(".card-header > .card-title").wrapInner("<button  class=\"btn btn-link\" type=\"button\" data-toggle=\"collapse\" aria-expanded=\"false\"></button>");
   $(value).find(".card-header > .card-title > button").attr({
      "data-target": "#collapse_acc_" + num,
      "aria-controls": "collapse_acc_" + num
   });
   $(value).children(".collapse").attr({
      id: "collapse_acc_" + num,
      "aria-labelledby": "heading_acc_" + num
   });
}));


$(document).ready(function(){
// Add class highlight to panel with show class
$(".collapse.show").each(function(){
    $(this).prev(".card-header").addClass("highlight");
});

// toggle highlight class
$(".card-header .btn").click(function(){
    $(".card-header").toggleClass("highlight");
});
});
```

```css
/* ========= Accordions ==========*/
.accordion .card .card-header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey
}

/* Accordion Standard */
.accordion:first-child {
  margin-top: 5px;
  border-radius: 0
}

.accordion h1,
.accordion h2,
.accordion h3,
.accordion h4,
.accordion h5,
.accordion h6 {
  font-size: 1.125rem
}

.accordion .card {
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0
}

.accordion .card .card-title {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0
}

.accordion .card .card-title button {
  color: black
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  padding: 1.25rem;
  border: 1px solid grey
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: #FFF;
  padding-left: 70px
}

.accordion .card .card-title button:hover,
.accordion .card .card-title button:focus {
  color: #174EA6
}

.accordion .card .card-title button::after {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  display: inline-block;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-rendering: auto;
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: "Font Awesome 6 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.5rem;
  left: 2rem
}

/* Open and Close Icon */
.accordion .card .card-title button[aria-expanded="true"]:after {
  content: "\f077";
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: .3s all;
  color: black
}

.accordion .card .card-title button[aria-expanded="false"]:after {
  content: "\f054";
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transition: .3s all;
  color: black
}

.accordion .card .card-header {
  padding: 0
}

.accordion .card .card-header button {
  border: 1px solid grey
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left
}

.accordion .card-body {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background-color: white
}

/* Active Accordion Panel - Background and Text Color */
.accordion .card .card-header button[aria-expanded="true"] {
  background-color: red;
  color: #ffffff
}

.accordion .card-header.highlight {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/4.6.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <link href=" https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/4.6.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    
    <h2>Accordion: Group of 2 - First panel open</h2>

       
            <!-- Accordion headings should be changed to respect page hierarchy -->
            <!--start accordion-->
            <div class="accordion mdb-shadow-4 my-5">
               <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header">
                     <h2 class="card-title">
                        Accordion 1 of 2
                     </h2>
                  </div>
                  <div class="collapse show">
                     <div class="card-body">
                        <p>Loren ipsum
                        </p>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header">
                     <h2 class="card-title">
                        Accordion 2 of 2
                     </h2>
                  </div>
                  <div class="collapse">
                     <div class="card-body">
                        <p>Insert Accordion 2 of 2 content here.</p>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <!--end accordion-->
```

Comment: It sounds like you intend to highlight _all_ open panels. Why not just use CSS?

Comment: @isherwood Indeed, the card-headers of all open panel have a colored background. This works well. But I also want the card-header of the panel that's open on page load to have the colored background. Can I accomplish this with CSS only?

Comment: Don't they all have the `show` class, regardless?

Comment: @isherwood No, only the panels that I want opened on page load.

Comment: Note that the version of Bootstrap you are learning reached its official [end-of-life](https://blog.getbootstrap.com/2022/07/19/bootstrap-4-6-2/) date 2 months ago.

Comment: @Yogi Spot on! I'm in the process of migration. However, it's something I do in my free time, so it's taking a while. Moreover, I'm a biologist and not a front-end developer making it more of a challenge for me! Stackoverflow really helps me oftentimes.

Comment: There are significant differences between Bootstrap 4 and 5 and some pain when switching. Like 5 now has a complete [accordion component](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/accordion/) which make some of what  you are learning here unnecessary.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also simplify a bit.  You're already dynamically adding the wrapper on your accordion components.  The only thing you're missing is that you're not setting the `aria-expanded` attribute to true for the ones that have the show property.  To do that you can check for the presence of the `show` class and add the value dynamically as follows:

```js
function addIds(index) {
  $(this).attr("id", "accordion_" + parseInt(index + 1));
}

function addDataAttrs(index, value) {
  const num = index + 1;
  // check if any child has the show class
  // the length of the array of elements will be 
  // either 0 (falsy) or a number greater than 0 (truthy)
  // use a ternary to store a string value of "true"
  // or "false" in the variable
  const isShowing = $(value).children(".show").length ? "true" : "false";

  $(value)
    .children(".card-header")
    .attr("id", "heading_acc_" + num);
  $(value)
    .find(".card-header > .card-title")
    .wrapInner(
      `<button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="${isShowing}"></button>`
    ); // use the variable to insert the correct value
  $(value)
    .find(".card-header > .card-title > button")
    .attr({
      "data-target": "#collapse_acc_" + num,
      "aria-controls": "collapse_acc_" + num
    });
  $(value)
    .children(".collapse")
    .attr({
      id: "collapse_acc_" + num,
      "aria-labelledby": "heading_acc_" + num
    });
}
```

Now there's no need to have the extra code to add the highlight class and thus you don't need it in your CSS either.

Working example below:

```js
const $accordions = $(".accordion");
const $cards = $(".accordion > .card");

$.each($accordions, addIds);
$.each($cards, addDataAttrs);

function addIds(index) {
  $(this).attr("id", "accordion_" + parseInt(index + 1));
}

function addDataAttrs(index, value) {
  const num = index + 1;
  const isShowing = $(value).children(".show").length ? "true" : "false";

  $(value)
    .children(".card-header")
    .attr("id", "heading_acc_" + num);
  $(value)
    .find(".card-header > .card-title")
    .wrapInner(
      `<button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="${isShowing}"></button>`
    );
  $(value)
    .find(".card-header > .card-title > button")
    .attr({
      "data-target": "#collapse_acc_" + num,
      "aria-controls": "collapse_acc_" + num
    });
  $(value)
    .children(".collapse")
    .attr({
      id: "collapse_acc_" + num,
      "aria-labelledby": "heading_acc_" + num
    });
}
```

```css
/* ========= Accordions ==========*/
.accordion .card .card-header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey
}

/* Accordion Standard */
.accordion:first-child {
  margin-top: 5px;
  border-radius: 0
}

.accordion h1,
.accordion h2,
.accordion h3,
.accordion h4,
.accordion h5,
.accordion h6 {
  font-size: 1.125rem
}

.accordion .card {
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0
}

.accordion .card .card-title {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0
}

.accordion .card .card-title button {
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  padding: 1.25rem;
  border: 1px solid grey
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: #FFF;
  padding-left: 70px;
}

.accordion .card .card-title button:hover,
.accordion .card .card-title button:focus {
  color: #174EA6;
}

.accordion .card .card-title button::after {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  display: inline-block;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-rendering: auto;
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: "Font Awesome 6 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.5rem;
  left: 2rem;
  transition: .3s all;
  color: black;
}

/* Open and Close Icon */
.accordion .card .card-title button[aria-expanded="true"]:after {
  content: "\f077";
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.accordion .card .card-title button[aria-expanded="false"]:after {
  content: "\f054";
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.accordion .card .card-header {
  padding: 0;
}

.accordion .card .card-header button {
/*   border: 1px solid grey; */
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left
}

.accordion .card-body {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background-color: white
}

/* Active Accordion Panel - Background and Text Color */
.accordion .card .card-header button[aria-expanded="true"] {
  background-color: red;
  color: #ffffff
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<h2>Accordion: Group of 2 - First panel open</h2>

       
<!-- Accordion headings should be changed to respect page hierarchy -->
<div class="accordion mdb-shadow-4 my-5">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <h2 class="card-title">
        Accordion 1 of 2
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse show">
      <div class="card-body">
        <p>Loren ipsum
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <h2 class="card-title">
        Accordion 2 of 2
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse">
      <div class="card-body">
        <p>Insert Accordion 2 of 2 content here.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/4.6.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href=" https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to select the **button** that receives the styles, and filter the **n** `.card` element opened . here  `.card:first-of-type`

Example

```js
/** Accordions JavaScript **/
/** Dynamically add id **/
$.each($(".accordion"), (function (index) {
   $(this).attr("id", "accordion_" + parseInt(index + 1));
}));

/** Dynamically add interaction **/
$.each($(".accordion > .card"), (function (index, value) {
   var num = index + 1;
   $(value).children(".card-header").attr("id", "heading_acc_" + num);
   $(value).find(".card-header > .card-title").wrapInner("<button  class=\"btn btn-link\" type=\"button\" data-toggle=\"collapse\" aria-expanded=\"false\"></button>");
   $(value).find(".card-header > .card-title > button").attr({
      "data-target": "#collapse_acc_" + num,
      "aria-controls": "collapse_acc_" + num
   });
   $(value).children(".collapse").attr({
      id: "collapse_acc_" + num,
      "aria-labelledby": "heading_acc_" + num
   });
}));


$(document).ready(function(){
// Add class highlight to panel with show class
$(".collapse.show").each(function(){
    $(this).prev(".card-header").addClass("highlight");
});

// toggle highlight class
$(".card:first-of-type .card-header .btn").click(function(){
    $(".card-header").toggleClass("highlight");
});
});
```

```css
/* ========= Accordions ==========*/
.accordion .card .card-header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey
}

/* Accordion Standard */
.accordion:first-child {
  margin-top: 5px;
  border-radius: 0
}

.accordion h1,
.accordion h2,
.accordion h3,
.accordion h4,
.accordion h5,
.accordion h6 {
  font-size: 1.125rem
}

.accordion .card {
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0
}

.accordion .card .card-title {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0
}

.accordion .card .card-title button {
  color: black
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  padding: 1.25rem;
  border: 1px solid grey
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: #FFF;
  padding-left: 70px
}

.accordion .card .card-title button:hover,
.accordion .card .card-title button:focus {
  color: #174EA6
}

.accordion .card .card-title button::after {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  display: inline-block;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-rendering: auto;
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: "Font Awesome 6 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.5rem;
  left: 2rem
}

/* Open and Close Icon */
.accordion .card .card-title button[aria-expanded="true"]:after {
  content: "\f077";
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: .3s all;
  color: black
}

.accordion .card .card-title button[aria-expanded="false"]:after {
  content: "\f054";
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transition: .3s all;
  color: black
}

.accordion .card .card-header {
  padding: 0
}

.accordion .card .card-header button {
  border: 1px solid grey
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left
}

.accordion .card-body {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background-color: white
}

/* Active Accordion Panel - Background and Text Color */
.accordion .card .card-header button[aria-expanded="true"] {
  background-color: red;
  color: #ffffff
}

.accordion .card:first-of-type .card-header.highlight  button {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/4.6.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <link href=" https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/4.6.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    
    <h2>Accordion: Group of 2 - First panel open</h2>

       
            <!-- Accordion headings should be changed to respect page hierarchy -->
            <!--start accordion-->
            <div class="accordion mdb-shadow-4 my-5">
               <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header ">
                     <h2 class="card-title">
                        Accordion 1 of 2
                     </h2>
                  </div>
                  <div class="collapse show">
                     <div class="card-body">
                        <p>Loren ipsum
                        </p>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header">
                     <h2 class="card-title">
                        Accordion 2 of 2
                     </h2>
                  </div>
                  <div class="collapse">
                     <div class="card-body">
                        <p>Insert Accordion 2 of 2 content here.</p>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <!--end accordion-->
```